# What am I, stalking you everyday?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I appear from the space
between the two planets
or between the two atoms

I am what a mouse and book
or a computer and air
have in common

When deceived, you shout my name
or when you are hiding your darkest secrets

I stalk you day and night
wherever you are
and Shark loves me

What am I, stalking you everyday?

Comment: can i flag this question as 'too narrow'? :D :p

Comment: `When deceived, you shout my name` made me thinks of Odysseus deceiving the cyclop by telling his name was `Nobody`, which more or less fits @Alconja's answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I've tried, but...

> **nothing**

...seems to fit . ;)

---

*I appear from the space / between the two planets / or between the two atoms*

> There's "nothing" between planets or atoms.

*I am what a mouse and book / or a computer and air / have in common*

> A mouse and a book have nothing in common, nor a computer and air.

*When deceived, you shout my name / or when you are hiding your darkest secrets*

> You're speechless when deceived, and you say nothing when hiding secrets.

*I stalk you day and night / wherever you are / and Shark loves me / What am I, stalking you everyday?*

> Nothing is stalking me (that's just paranoia), and Shark(?) clearly loves nothing.

Comment: It does indeed work, waiting in suspense for acceptance of the answer :p

Comment: Boo! I thought of this, but it doesn't really apply. For example, a book and a mouse have several things in common (a **spine**, the **letter O**, a **tale** / **tail**, ...)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - yeah, it requires pretty poetic interpretations of "nothing", because I'm sure physicists would have problems with the first verse too.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain But a computer and air have virtually nothing in common. Other than they are made of atoms???

Comment: @Daedric They both contain an R, they are both required to fly a drone...   You can find connections between just about any two things, which is why the whole premise of this question is flawed.

Comment: When I say Shark, I mean the company because in space, nothing is practically a vacuum.

Comment: @PythonMaster - Ahh. Makes sense. Wasn't familiar with the brand.